# Setting a theme for an app

Tags: android, styles, themes

Can I set a theme for the app I create?

I am talking about themes like in...

http://developer.android.com/design/style/themes.html

or should I use Styles and themes, and individually modify every child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed have to use [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

You can add a theme to whole of your application with just one line in the manifest:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Comment: are there any in-built themes that I can use?

Comment: Yes. Those mentioned in the link that you have shared. That is for the Ice Cream Sandwich devices. For earlier one's ,search the Android docs, you will find a few.